# como saber nombre estudiante?

Tags: python

Me piden: Escriba un programa en Python que permita procesar el nombre y la edad de los 150 estudiantes de una universidad. Por ejemplo, una entrada válida del programa sería el valor 25 para la edad del estudiante, y “ Agustín” para el nombre.

Una vez procesados todos los estudiantes, el programa debe informar:

a) El promedio de edad de los estudiantes del curso.

b) Indicar (por sí o por no) si algún estudiante del curso se llama “ Pedro ”.

c) El nombre del estudiante con mayor edad del curso.

pude resolver el a y el c pero me trabe con el b si me dan un mano se los agradecería.

```
def programa(Edad_alumno,Nombre_alumno,edad_total,edad_maxima,nombre_alumno,nombres_totales,Repeticiones):
for i in range (2,151):
    Nombre = input(f'Ingrese el nombre del alumno de introduccion a la programacion [{i}-150]: ')
    Edad = int(input(f'Ingrese la edad del alumno de introduccion a la programacion [{i}-150]:'))

    nombres_totales = nombres_totales + 1
    edad_total =  edad_total + Edad
    

    if Edad > edad_maxima:
        edad_maxima = Edad
        Nombre_Max = Nombre
    elif Edad == Edad_alumno:
        Repeticiones = Repeticiones + 1
    
Promedio_total_de_edades = edad_total / nombres_totales


print('El promedio de edad de los estudiantes del curso es de ' + str(Promedio_total_de_edades))
print('El nombre del estudiante con mayor edad del curso es ' + str(Nombre_Max))               


Nombre_alumno = input('Ingrese el nombre del alumno de introduccion a la programacion [1-150]: ')
Edad_alumno = int(input('Ingrese la edad del alumno de introduccion a la programacion [1-150]:'))
edad_total = Edad_alumno
edad_maxima = Edad_alumno
nombre_alumno = Nombre_alumno
nombres_totales = 1
Repeticiones
programa(Edad_alumno,Nombre_alumno,edad_total,edad_maxima,nombre_alumno,nombres_totales,Repeticiones)
```

Comment: Para empezar, no estás guardando los nombres en ningún lado, cómo pretendes saber si uno se llama Pedro? Tendrás que tener una lista de nombres donde vas metiendo los nombres de cada alumno, luego podrás mirar los elementos de la lista para ver si alguno coincide. (En vez de una lista puedes utilizar un [`set`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_sets.asp), a diferencia de la lista, el set no mantendrá el orden en que ingresas los elementos, pero no admite duplicados así que no tendrás nombres repetidos

Comment: no tengo permitido usar listas ni vectores sino ya lo podía haber resuelto igual gracias por tu aporte

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quizás esto te sirva:

```
def programa():
    esta_pedro = False
    edad_maxima = -1
    nombres_totales = 0
    edad_total = 0
    Nombre_Max = ""
    for i in range(150):
        Nombre = input(f'Ingrese el nombre del alumno de introducción a la programación [{i+1}-150]: ')
        Edad = int(input(f'Ingrese la edad del alumno de introducción a la programación [{i+1}-150]:'))

        nombres_totales += 1
        edad_total += Edad

        if Edad > edad_maxima:
            edad_maxima = Edad
            Nombre_Max = Nombre
        if Nombre == "Pedro":
            esta_pedro = True
    Promedio_total_de_edades = edad_total / nombres_totales if nombres_totales > 0 else 0

    print('El promedio de edad de los estudiantes del curso es de ' + str(Promedio_total_de_edades))
    print('Pedro sí está en el curso' if esta_pedro else 'Pedro no está en el curso')
    print('El nombre del estudiante con mayor edad del curso es ' + str(Nombre_Max))

programa()
```

Este no es exactamente tu código, pero hace lo mismo y sin usar arreglos. Aún así, en tu propio código sólo tienes que declarar la variable `esta_pedro = False` arriba de `def programa2(Edad_alumno, Nombre_alumno, edad_total, edad_maxima, nombre_alumno, nombres_totales, Repeticiones):` y dentro de ese método y antes del `for` poner `global esta_pedro`; luego entre los dos `print` que están fuera del `for`: `print('Pedro sí está en el curso' if esta_pedro else 'Pedro no está en el curso')`

Si deseas utilizar arreglos:

```
def programa():
    arreglo1 = []
    arreglo2 = []
    for i in range(150):
        Nombre = input(f'Ingrese el nombre del alumno de introducción a la programación [{i+1}-150]: ')
        Edad = int(input(f'Ingrese la edad del alumno de introducción a la programación [{i+1}-150]:'))
        arreglo1.append(Nombre)
        arreglo2.append(Edad)
    print('El promedio de edad de los estudiantes del curso es de ' +
          str(sum(arreglo2) / len(arreglo1) if len(arreglo2) > 0 else 0))
    print('Pedro sí está en el curso' if "Pedro" in arreglo1 else 'Pedro no está en el curso')
    print('El nombre del estudiante con mayor edad del curso es ' + arreglo1[arreglo2.index(max(arreglo2))])

programa()
```